# java with if statement for checkboxes gui

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement

Hi all could you please assist with implementing the following:
-drop and drap menu for style pizza gui
meat: ham, chicken and pepperoni
seafood: prawns, mussels and scallops
vegetable: choose from the additional toppings list

-help menu bar with help and exit

-request / add new topping button with pop up box asking the user to enter topping followed by two other buttons below one for Request when clicked it sends the topping to email address or if add topping is clicked another pop up box asking admin to enter authorization code which is set at 123456 and then click another button saying add topping which adds the topping to the topping menu

-a 2d drwaing

Here is my code so far:

```
//Packages
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class CaseyPizza extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pizzaPanel, centerPanel, pricePanel, checkBoxPanel, radioButtonPanel;
    private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
    private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
    private ButtonGroup group;
    private JRadioButton smallButton, mediumButton, largeButton;
    private JCheckBox olivCheckBox, mushCheckBox, pineapCheckBox, capsiCheckBox;
    private JTextField priceTextField;
    private double price = 0.0;
    private double topPrice = 0.0;
    private double showPrice = 0.0;
    private ActionListener listener = new PriceListener();
    public CaseyPizza() {
        pizzaPanel = new JPanel();
        pizzaPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        createRadioButtonPanel();
        createCheckBoxPanel();
        createPricePanel();
        createCenterPanel();

        pizzaPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pizzaPanel.add(pricePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame = new JFrame("Casey Pizza Ordering System");
        frame.add(pizzaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void createRadioButtonPanel() {
        radioButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        radioButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        radioButtonPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Size"));
        group = new ButtonGroup();
        smallButton = new JRadioButton(" Small ");
        group.add(smallButton);
        smallButton.addActionListener(listener);
        radioButtonPanel.add(smallButton);
        mediumButton = new JRadioButton(" Medium ");
        group.add(mediumButton);
        mediumButton.addActionListener(listener);
        radioButtonPanel.add(mediumButton);
        largeButton = new JRadioButton(" Large ");
        group.add(largeButton);
        largeButton.addActionListener(listener);
        radioButtonPanel.add(largeButton);
    }

    // add the check boxes to this frame
    // add action listener for the check boxes
    private void createCheckBoxPanel() {
        checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();
        checkBoxPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        olivCheckBox = new JCheckBox(" Olives ");
        olivCheckBox.addActionListener(listener);
        checkBoxPanel.add(olivCheckBox);
        mushCheckBox = new JCheckBox(" Mushrooms ");
        mushCheckBox.addActionListener(listener);
        checkBoxPanel.add(mushCheckBox);
        pineapCheckBox = new JCheckBox(" Pineapple ");
        pineapCheckBox.addActionListener(listener);
        checkBoxPanel.add(pineapCheckBox);
        capsiCheckBox = new JCheckBox(" Capsicum ");
        capsiCheckBox.addActionListener(listener);
        checkBoxPanel.add(capsiCheckBox);
    }

    //Price Panel
    private void createPricePanel() {
        pricePanel = new JPanel();
        pricePanel.add(new JLabel("Your Price:"));
        priceTextField = new JTextField(7);
        priceTextField.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        priceTextField.setEditable(false);
        priceTextField.setForeground(Color.blue);
        priceTextField.setBackground(pricePanel.getBackground());
        priceTextField.setDisabledTextColor(Color.blue);
        priceTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        pricePanel.add(priceTextField);
        priceTextField.setText(" n/a Price");
    }
    private void createCenterPanel() {
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.add(radioButtonPanel);
        centerPanel.add(checkBoxPanel);
    }



    //Method for price of pizza build
    private class PriceListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            topPrice = 0;
            if (smallButton.isSelected()) {
                price = 3.00;
            } else if (mediumButton.isSelected()) {
                price = 6.00;
            } else if (largeButton.isSelected()) {
                price = 8.00;
            }

            if(olivCheckBox.isSelected())
            {
                topPrice += 0.50;
            }
            if(mushCheckBox.isSelected())
            {
                topPrice += 0.50;
            }
            if(pineapCheckBox.isSelected())
            {
                topPrice += 0.50;
            }
            if(capsiCheckBox.isSelected())
            {
                topPrice += 0.50;
}
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showPrice = price + topPrice;
                    priceTextField.setText(" $" + showPrice);
                    System.out.println("Price dispayed");
                }
            });
        }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CaseyPizza pPF = new CaseyPizza();
                System.out.println("Run");
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: If all the ingredients are 0.50, why not start at 0 and simply use a if statement and add 0.50 for each selected item, instead of using a if-else-if...?

Comment: I have 4 check boxes oliv, mush, pineap and capsi. each are set at $0.50 so I need to work out how to make it so if for each combination and set of chosen checkboxes to calculate. It is currently only calculating the oliv and mush when ticked in the checked box

Comment: Yes my knowledge goes as far as two calculations though not four, if you could share your knowledge of how to implement what you said that would be great

Comment: @CaseyT Can do, check answer...

Comment: @CaseyT, do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point, but...

If each topping is `0.50` each, why not just use a series of `if` statements to check which check boxes are selected and add `0.50` to the `topPrice`, for example...

```
topPrice = 0;
if(olivCheckBox.isSelected())
{
    topPrice += 0.50;
}
if(mushCheckBox.isSelected())
{
    topPrice += 0.50;
}
if(pineapCheckBox.isSelected())
{
    topPrice += 0.50;
}
if(capsiCheckBox.isSelected())
{
    topPrice += 0.50;
}
```

You could even put them in an array and simply loop over it...

```
JCheckBox toppings[] = new JCheckBox[] {
    olivCheckBox,
    mushCheckBox,
    pineapCheckBox,
    capsiCheckBox
};
topPrice = 0;
for (JCheckBox topping : toppings) {
    if (topping.isSelected()) {
        topPrice += 0.50;
    }
}
```

This way, you wouldn't need to re-write a lot of code if you wanted to add more toppings...

Comment: your first series of if statements work however the problem I am experiencing now is pineap and capsi do not calculate and add .50

Comment: Awesome thanks works well now. if i were to ask for more knowledge to implement other features could you help and how can i do it?

Comment: Best thing is to try something and ask more questions ;)

Comment: I re posted my questions above with my full code so far it is a really hard task all this gui so much coding and to get it all working together without knowledge yet learned is even more difficult. I cant even find resources or help to integrate it all together

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
if (olivCheckBox.isSelected() && mushCheckBox.isSelected() && pineapCheckBox.isSelected() && capsiCheckBox.isSelected()){
```

similarly change for all other else if statements

or something like

`if( (olivCheckBox.isSelected()) && (mushCheckBox.isSelected()) && (pineapCheckBox.isSelected()) && (capsiCheckBox.isSelected()))`{

for all if / else if statements

you have incorrect syntax in first three conditionals:

```
if ((olivCheckBox.isSelected()) && (mushCheckBox.isSelected()) && (pineapCheckBox.isSelected()) && (capsiCheckBox.isSelected())){
                topPrice = 2.00;
            } else if ((olivCheckBox.isSelected()) && (mushCheckBox.isSelected()) && (pineapCheckBox.isSelected())) {
                topPrice = 1.50;
            } else if ((olivCheckBox.isSelected()) && (mushCheckBox.isSelected())) {
                topPrice = 1.00;
            }
```

you are missing parentheses for if / else if.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge it makes sense but still is not working. It calculates olives and mushrooms check boxes but not pineapple and capsicum checkboxes or when all 4 are checked

Comment: check your order of if else statements for that, try reversing the order